# Prevent click button to append content multiple times

Tags: jquery

Hi i have a code to open a external link on overlay

```
    $('body').append('<div class="overlay-2"><div class="contentWrap"></div>  </div>');
    $("a.overlay-2[rel]").live('click', function () {
    $("a.overlay-2[rel]").overlay({
        mask: '#333',
        onBeforeLoad: function() {
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
            wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        }
    }).load();

    $(this).overlay().load();       
    return false;
});
```

This append the div overlay-contato

the first click on link open everything normal, but each time i close the overlay and click again the code is append the div to body multiple times.

the button code is

```
    <a href="/php/my-page.php"  class="overlay-2" rel=".overlay-contato">click </a>
```

Comment: Can you show us on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()`  to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()`  in preference to `.live()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a check to see if the div you are potentially going to append exists first.

```
// note i added an id to the overlay to simplify and improve selector performance
var overlay = $('#overlay');

if(overlay.length < 1) {
  overlay = $('<div id="overlay" class="overlay-2"><div class="contentWrap"></div></div>').appendTo('body');
}

// now you can also use overlay as a variable instead of querying it from the DOM
```

Comment: or remove it before you add it everytime.

Comment: Hi @prodigitalson your sugestion fixed the problem, but i m confuse, looking on the code every time i open the overlay, all content from jquery like lightbox is append to the body multiple times. Like when i open the site first time i check the code there on final of the page have 1 lightbox div, 1 overlay etc. with your solution the overlay dont repeat anymore but all others is append multiple times.

Comment: then you need to add the same type of check if you are appending to the others. You didnt post that code, so i wouldnt have commented on it.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the overlay outside of the click handler. Each time you click you are creating a new instance of the overlay when all you want to do is display it